# Can`t run first web application Tomcat + Intellij

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I`m trying to run my first simple web application.
I have one class:

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

I used Maven to build my project.
After install the project i made follow settings in Tomcat configuration
[TOMCAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46xkT.png)

After run the configuration i see, that deployment completed successful
[CONFIGURATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odACb.png)

But when i`m trying to open localhost:8080/ i observe Tomcat home page, also at localhost:8080/mypage.jsp

What should i do, to see my "Hello world"?

Comment: Could you at least inline your images ?

Comment: is your servlet mapped in web.xml ? I don't see annotations so you should have something like <servlet-mappin> in your web.xml

Comment: @Marged sorry, but i haven`t enough reputation to paste inline images(( this is my first question on SOF

Comment: @BigMike Yes, i have web.xml it contains:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>service.MainServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
i also tried with annotations, but it gives the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a new answer since the last one was too long and didn't hit the spot.

your problem is different than a simple naming problem the problem is the fact that you use JEE API dependency

```
           <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
               <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            </dependency>

<!-- the other dependencies -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javaee</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

that get packaged in your war and this API JUST gives you packages with Mock classes that have same name and same method but there is no logic inside And the server is responsible for providing the real implementation with some logic inside, So this dependency should be marked with scope provided which means that they should not be packaged in WAR or they will throw an exception at runtime or even at deployment time, so you marked as i said with scope provided like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

<!-- the other dependencies -->  
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javaee</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Advice**

mark the dependency of tomcat with scope provided since your server Tomcat will provide those packages you don't need to have them inside you war
so do like this

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
your advice was very helpful!